# Viewpager with Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a bar which includes menu. Im using viewbar and i need to show my bar every single page.

So thats why i created my bar in MainActivity and viewpager_layout.xml

If i use same fragment layout every page its working well but when i try change layout its suck. Here my code.

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapterViewPager = new viewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    vpPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    getBottomBar();

    // Attach the page change listener inside the activity
    vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Seçilen sayfa: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (position == 0)
            {
                bottomNavigationBar.selectTab(0);
            }
            if (position == 1)
            {
                bottomNavigationBar.selectTab(1);
            }
        }

        // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // Code goes here
        }

        // Called when the scroll state changes:
        // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // Code goes here
        }
    });
}
BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationBar;
private void getBottomBar() {
    bottomNavigationBar = (BottomNavigationBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);

    bottomNavigationBar
            .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.home, "Anasayfa"))
            .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.group, "Gruplar"))
            .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.counter, "Votloc"))
            .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.date, "Profil"))
            .addItem(new BottomNavigationItem(R.drawable.password, "Daha Fazla"))
            .initialise();
    bottomNavigationBar.setTabSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationBar.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(int position) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(int position) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(int position) {
        }
    });
    bottomNavigationBar
            .setMode(BottomNavigationBar.MODE_FIXED);
    bottomNavigationBar
            .setBackgroundStyle(BottomNavigationBar.BACKGROUND_STYLE_RIPPLE);
    bottomNavigationBar
            .setActiveColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
            .setInActiveColor("#FFFFFF")
            .setBarBackgroundColor("#FF1717");


}
```

viewpager_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

What should I do for use my bar every single page.
Am I have to create bar in every fragments ?

Comment: Your Toolbar should not be a part of a page in your ViewPager. If you declare the toolbar outside of your view pager then you will have it on a screen no matter what page is selected.

Comment: so am  have to add my bar to every fragment ?

Comment: No, that's the opposite of what I just said :) In your activity layout you have a Toolbar and a ViewPager. The view pager will show pages which are fragments. Each fragment can have its own layout, but the toolbar should not be in the fragments layout, it should be in activity's layout

Comment: Yeah its what i want. But i cant show my toolbar.Its looking wihout menus in the first fragment and in my secpnd fragment its not showing itself. But when i pick same layout for both of fragment its looking awesome.

Comment: We probably don't understand each other. If the toolbar is outside the viewpager then it will look the same no matter what fragment is currently shown. Because toolbar is not a part of a fragment, it's a part of activity. I think you should attach screenshots so that I can understand the problem.

Comment: First fragment -> http://i.hizliresim.com/OAQlVZ.png

Comment: Second fragment -> http://i.hizliresim.com/MpqZvg.png

Comment: Its wont show menu items and in the second fragment its also wont show toolbar too.

Comment: It could be nice for earn reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized it was because I used `<include>` to add the `ListView` to my fragment from another layout resource file.

After that I created a new layout file and I just included my `ListView` directly into the new layout file. Then I used this new layout file for `myMainFragment.java` file and finally my `ViewPager` works well.